# Semi-advanced PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

So I'm new to Arrays, but I think this should be fairly easy, I just can't wrap my head around it.

I've got an array, that can have a varying amount of keys in it, based on how much input is given by the user.

```
$array = MY_Class( array(
   'type' => 'representatives', 
   'show_this_many' => '10'
));
```

easy enough, right?

but I've got 1-4 more keys that could be in it, based on user input. They fill out a form on the first page, and it submits to the second page (which contains the array above).

I need to grab **City**, **State**, **First**, **last**, based on how many fields the user fills out on the previous page. I can't have blank ones so

```
$array = MY_Class( array(
   'type' => 'representatives', 
   'show_this_many' => '10',
   'city' => '',
   'state' => '',
   'first' => $_GET['first']
));
```

won't really work. I need a way to determine which fields have been submitted (preferrably via `GET`) and build the array that way. so can end up with

```
 $array = MY_Class( array(
   'type' => 'representatives', 
   'show_this_many' => '10',
   'state' => $_GET['state'],
   'first' => $_GET['first']
));
```

because **state** and **first** had a value while **city** and **last** did not.

The first thing that came to mind was something like

```
$array = MY_Class( array(
   'type' => 'representatives', 
   'show_this_many' => '10',
   $constants => $variables
));

//where
$constants = array( //_GET stuff values );
$variables = array( //_GET stuff with values );

// magic method to make it like
//  CONSTANTS[0] => VARIABLES[0];
//  CONSTANTS[1] => VARIABLES[1];
// so everything is lined up
```

but I'm not sure how to do it :/

Comment: Simply merge `$_GET` with your config array. Or if you don't want all entries, define a whitelist and copy only those values.

Comment: `$array = MY_Class( array(` this line doesn't make much sense. You would have to use the `new` keyword if you are trying to instantiate an object.

Comment: This seems a crazy way to get around a simple class with setters - [it's time to give it a go](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

Comment: @PeeHaa - sorry, I was writing that on the fly. But, it DOES have `new MY_Class` in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use a whitelist of possible keys from `$_GET` so your array doesn't get polluted with spurious (or possibly malicious) keys, and then you can simply append them onto your array with a loop over `$_GET`.

```
// Your array is already initialized with some values:
$array = array(
  'type' => 'representatives', 
  'show_this_many' => '10' 
);

// Allowed GET keys
$allowed = array('city','state','first');

// Loop over get and add the keys (if allowed)
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
  // If the key is allowed and the value isn't blank...
  if (in_array($allowed, $key) && !empty($value)) {
    $array[$key] = $value;
  }
}

// See all the newly added keys...
var_dump($array);
```

Another option is to just add all the keys to the array, then call [`array_filter()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove the blanks.

```
$array = array(
  'type' => 'representatives', 
  'show_this_many' => '10',
  'city' => '', 
  'state' => '',
  'first' => ''
);
// Add values from $_GET, then filter it
$array = array_filter($array, function($val) {
  return $val !== '' && !is_null($val);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
$array = array(
  'type' => 'representatives', 
  'show_this_many' => '10'
);

$fields = array ('city', 'state', 'first');

foreach ($fields as $field) {
  if (!empty($_GET[$field])) {
    $array[$field]  = $_GET[$field]
  }
}
```